# I am able to add a UITapGestureRecognizer to my controllers self.view, but not to any custom views. Why?

Tags: objective-c, swift, cocoa-touch, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have my ViewController conforming to the UIGestureRecognizerDelegate.

I have various views created in this ViewController. A custom view called circleView, and a regular UIView called testView.

I have the following function which is called from viewDidLoad

```
func addTapGesturesOnNumberPadDisplay() {
    if tapGestureRecognizerNumberPadView == nil {
        tapGestureRecognizerNumberPadView = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "handleTap:")
        tapGestureRecognizerNumberPadView!.delegate = self
        //self.circleView!.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizerNumberPadView!) // 1
        //self.testView!.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizerNumberPadView!) // 2
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizerNumberPadView!) // 3
    }
}
```

This code works, with line 3 active. My `func handleTap(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {` is triggered. But if I comment out line 3, and make either line 1 or 2 active... `handleTap:` is never hit.

Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that `userInteractionEnabled` is set to true of your `UIView's`. And also here the hierarchy matters.

If you have any `UIView` on the top of `circleView` and `testView` then it won't work.

Apart from that, the third line works because you are adding the `UITapGestureRecognizer` to the `superview` of the `UIViewController`.

Comment: thanks, it's been a week since I worked on this, and I forgot I have a drawView overlaying everything to draw "finger trailing lines". So the drawView was preventing any of my taps from being recognized. Can you add the same gestureRezognizer to multiple views? that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @chrisP Make sure you never undergo this mistake. Glad to help :)